# How do I create a Pivot Layout in Adaptable

Tags: datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using Adaptable with ag-Grid React.  I saw a video which said that a Pivot Layout can be created in configuration but I cannot work out how to do it.

I am able to create and save 'normal' Layouts but I would like AdapTable to start up with my data in ag-Grid pivot view.

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same way you create a non-pivot Layout - though Layout Predefined Config.
The Layout section has an `enablePivot` property which you should set to true and a `PivotColumns` collection where you list the columns that you want to be pivoted.  RowGrouped and Aggregation columns can also be set (as with a non-pivot layout).
See docs at: https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/predefined-config/layout-config

There is a demo at: https://demo.adaptabletools.com/layout/aggridpivotlayoutdemo

The config for that Layout is as follows:

```
Layout: {
    CurrentLayout: 'Pivot View',
    Layouts: [
      {
        Columns: [],
        ColumnSorts: [],
        RowGroupedColumns: ['Employee'],
        PivotColumns: ['ShipVia', 'ShipCountry'],
        AggregationColumns: { InvoicedCost: 'sum', ItemCount: 'max' },
        EnablePivot: true,
        Name: 'Pivot View',
      },
    ],
  },
```